# How do shared CloudKit containers allocate data usage?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

With iOS 10 CloudKit can now share private containers. Is the storage space requirement shared among the users or does it only count against one user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it only counts against the one user who owns the original shared record.:

> So, the correct way to add a new record via the shared database is to set a Parent Reference and link it to the shared hierarchy.
>
> So, even though you're adding a new record for the participant via the shared database, that new record lives in the owner's private DB.
>
> So, what this means is all records that are added by the participant are counted against the owner's quota.
>
> So, the producement's quota is not affected and your developer quota is not affected.
>
> The owner's private database is the only place that we store these records so we can count them only against the owner's quota.

From [WWDC 2016, 226](http://asciiwwdc.com/2016/sessions/226).